# Stopping an draggable object from dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, limit

I'm currently working on a drag and drop plugin. I want to add a feature so the user can limit the amount of times the drggable object can be dragged and dropped. I will call this feature, dragLimitation.

This is what I have so far:

```
var limit = 0;
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $(oj).mouseup(function() {
                        if (o.dragLimitation !== false) {
                           if (limit > (o.dragLimitation-1)) {
                           //Code to Stop Drag Here
                            } else {
                                limit++;
                                $('#back').html(limit);
                            }
                        }

                    });
                });
```

**About the Code:** There are couple of things I want to get clear to you guys so I can get an answer.

The var, oj in: `$(oj).mouseup(function() {` is just referring to `this`. In this case `this` would be:  `$('#drag').jDrag();`, which is just to get my plugin running.

`#drag` = `this`

One thing I want to point out is `o.dragLimitation`. This is to get the amount of times the drag and drop item/object can be dropped(mouseup).

Example:

```
$('#drag').jDrag({
dragLimitation: 20
});
```

This would make `#drag` be able to be dragged and dropped **`20`** times.

I got a lot of the code but I just don't know how to stop the element from dragging. I don't to break the code either using:

```
$('body').append('<span>');
```

So the users can still use the rest of the page.

Here is where the code for the stop dragging should be:

```
if (limit > (o.dragLimitation - 1)) {
    //Code to Stop Drag Here
}
```

I really hope someone can help me with the details I gave.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function($) {
  $.extend($.fn, {
    jDrag: function() {
      var dragCount = this.data("jDrag.dragCount"),
          limitation = this.data("jDrag.limitation");

      if(typeof dragCount !== "number" || !isFinite(dragCount))
          {
            /*
             * Drag count isn't a valid number.
             * Give it a 0 value, and save it to the target.
             */

            dragCount = 0;
            this.data("jDrag.dragCount", dragCount);
          }

      if(typeof limiation !== "number" || !isFinite(limitation))
          {
            /*
             * Limitation isn't a valid number.
             * Load default limitation from plugin defaults.
             */

            limitation = $.data("jDrag.defaults").limitation;
          }

      if(dragCount <= limitation)
          {
            /*
             * Drag limitation isn't yet exceeded, increment count
             * and save it to the target.
             */

            this.data("jDrag.dragCount", ++dragCount);

            /* Continue code here. */
          }
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Refer to [jQuery.data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method for internally storing data for your plugins. As you can probably see, the code above simply loads the amount of times the target has been dragged, and the limitation placed on the target. If the dragCount isn't a valid number, it gives it a dragCount of zero (, later changed to 1). If the limitation isn't a valid number, it loads the plugin's default limitation stored in the plugin's data.

Notice that we used `this.data`, but we later used `$.data`. When using `this.data`, this information is stored on the specific element. Using `$.data` will load data for the plugin itself. Since we use `this.data` to store information on the specific element, you can easily store different drag limitations on different elements, instead of making them all share the same limitations. If you follow this outline, you shouldn't have any problems.

**Note:** I didn't test this script. It is just a basic idea.

---

**Update:** Added comments to code for better understanding.

Comment: So when adding this code. It should work? And I put my full plugin in the place of the comment tag that say: Continue code here.

Comment: this might be to difficult, Because I have to add the options and everything

Comment: You'll have to adapt your code to work with the layout above. You can't just paste things into place and expect them to work. If you wait, I'll post a link to a JSFiddle example.

Comment: Here is a working demo that demonstrates how to disable dragging after so many times of being dragged, but as for the actual dragging, I think I typed enough already. It'll be up to you to create the plugin's actual functionality. [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dEYfk/2) for the demo.

I tested it with Google Chrome using jQuery version 1.7.1, So I hope you're using Google Chrome as well. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

You don't necessarily need any *code* to stop the drag/drop functionality, you should just wrap the code *for* the drag/drop functionality in an *if* that checks if the limitation has been met. If it has then the dragging/dropping code wont execute.

Comment: I thought of doing this but I didnt want to